# What's wrong with my partition table?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

My Ubuntu OS does not recognise any external drives or devices. This started after I installed Windows XP. When I run GParted, it shows "unallocated 465.76 GiB". I ran "sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda" and this is what I got-

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1         4001790   108857343    52427777    5  Extended
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2        45946880   108857343    31455232   83  Linux
/dev/sda3   *   108872505   171766979    31447237+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda4       171771904   976773119   402500608    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5         4001792    45944831    20971520   83  Linux
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my partition table. Please help.

This is a screenshot of gparted:-
[image: GParted Screenshot]

Comment: There is something wrong with my partition table. Two partitions have overlapped. How will updating kernel help??

Comment: in some cases updating the current kernal will detect the external devices connected.

Comment: I recently updated my kernel. It's got nothing to do with it. The problem is with partitions overlapping. Only I can't figure out which partitions are overlapping and how to fix it.

Comment: upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/405759/partition-table-gone-and-bad-mbr-trying-to-recover-through-testdisk

Answer (score 0):

You can check GParted -> Information for more details ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2013484)). It is likely your partition table is violating some of the rules of [ms-dos partition tables](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php).